# Hide Bottom Tab Bar when using a coustem tab bar option react navigagtion version 6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to hide the tab bar in a specific screen in react-navigation previously it's possible by passing

`tabBarVisible prop`

But now I am using a custom tab bar with the help of tabBar prop, Is there any way to hide the bottom tab bar on some screens.

And how to hide the tab bar when the keyboard is active, Already tried `tabBarHideOnKeyboard​`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who experiencing the same issue, Nesting the tab navigator inside a stack navigator solved my problem its a bit more complicated than using `tabBarVisible` as we need to restructure the code, For ref [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/)

And couldn't find any good solution for the second part of my problem if I find any I will update my answer